# CSS background image wont be loaded and code wont be updated

Tags: html, css

*in my CSS file, I coded*

```css
/*The code I write*/
.wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/homeTrans2.svg) no-repeat top right/ cover;
}
```

**Note: I made sure to save my work**

but when I try to load it, my computer reads the code as

```css
/*The code when the computer reads it*/
.wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30%;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(./img/homeTrans2.svg) no-repeat top right/ cover;
}
```

**NOTE: notice the number of dots in the background URL**

*why can't I access my file?*

**NOTE: I know I can reorganize my files to make it work, but I wnt my folders more organized**

Comment: What did you mean when you say "when computer reads it"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the image in the same directory of your project then change the path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `background` to `background: url('../img/homeTrans2.svg') no-repeat top right/ cover;` or with double-quotes. Some browsers may not pick up relative URLs correctly.